# AngularJS + RequireJS + NgNestable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, requirejs

Fala galera, tudo bem? Então estou trabalhando com RequireJS junto com AngularJS, hoje precisei trabalhar com uma lib de NgNestable

[kamilkp/ng-nestable](https://github.com/kamilkp/ng-nestable)

Porém quando tento carregar a diretiva no meu app da seguinte forma:

```
define(['angularamd', 'angular-uirouter', 'angular-nestable'], function (angularAMD) {

    var app = angular.module('appFerramentaria', [
        'ui.router',
        'ng-nestable'
    ]);

    {...}
});
```

O seguinte erro é retornado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Esse é o meu arquivo de configuração do RequireJS *(main.js)*, acredito que o erro pode estar na ordem em que estou chamando os arquivos

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/portais/colaborador_novo/assets_novo/js',
    urlArgs: "v=" +  (new Date()).getTime(),// desenv
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'jquery.min',
        'bootstrap': 'bootstrap-rjs.min',
        'angular': 'angular1-7.min',
        'angular-uirouter': 'angular-ui-router.min',
        'angularamd': 'angularAMD.min',
        'jquery.nestable': 'jquery.nestable',
        'angular-nestable': 'angular-nestable',
        'app': '../../app/views/ferramentaria/app',
    },
    shim: {
        'angular': ['jquery', 'bootstrap'],
        'angularamd': ['angular'],
        'angular-uirouter': ['angular', 'angularamd'],
        'jquery.nestable': ['jquery'],
        'angular-nestable': ['jquery.nestable', 'angular']
    },
    deps: [
        'app'
    ]
});
```

Desde já agradeço, valeu :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá depois de muito revirar achei uma solução:

```
shim: {
    'angular': {
        deps: ['jquery', 'bootstrap'],
        exports: 'angular'
    },
{...}
```